# Create all binary valued vectors of specific length

Tags: python, pytorch

How do I efficiently create a matrix of shape `(2**N, N)` with all binary vectors of length N as its rows? I call a vector binary iff each of its components equals either 0 or 1. I want the matrix to have `dtype=torch.float`.

Comment: have you tried list comprehension?

Comment: When you say `all binary vectors of length N`, do you mean every possible binary vector, in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seb's answer but modified for pytorch:

```py
def gen_all_binary_vectors(length: int) -> torch.Tensor:
    return ((torch.arange(2**length).unsqueeze(1) >> torch.arange(length-1, -1, -1)) & 1).float()
```

Answer (score 3):

For modest values of `N`, this may work alright:

```
import numpy as np

def bin_array(N, dtype):
    return (np.arange(1<<N, dtype=dtype)[:, None] >> np.arange(N, dtype=dtype)[::-1]) & 0b1
```

For maximum efficiency though, I'd suggest to generate the individual bits packed in `uint8` values and design the arithmetic to operate on that. This will depend on what exactly you want to do with the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
import random
import torch
res = [ [ random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(2**N) ] for j in range(N) ]
pt_tensor_from_list = torch.FloatTensor(res)
```